# Smoothly animate background color opacity after underlying image loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a black background.  When my page loads, I make a call for an `image` and then load that `image` into a `div` behind the main `div`.  Then I want to smoothly fade the overlaying `div` to have an opacity so that the image underneath is displayed, but without impacting the opacity of content in the overlaying `div`.

What I have isn't really working at all: https://jsfiddle.net/n7t2xmha/3/

- The animation is not smooth
- The opacity is not accurate
- The text does not stay solid

**Code:**

```
<div class="outerdiv">
    <div class="innerdiv">
    </div>
    <p>
        content - should remain solid white
    </p>
</div>

.outerdiv {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    color: white;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.outerdiv-opaque {
    opacity: 0.9 !important;
}

.innerdiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index=-1;
}
```

**JS**

```
var innerDiv = $('.innerdiv');
setTimeout(function() {
    innerDiv.css('background-image', 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxR09.png)');
    var outerdiv = $('.outerdiv');
    setTimeout(function() {
        outerdiv.addClass('outerdiv-opaque');
    }, 500);

}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the timeouts functions.
modify the .outerdiv-opaque class

```
   .outerdiv-opaque {
      background-color: white;
    }
```

your timeOut functions after separating would look like this

```
    var innerDiv = $('.innerdiv');
setTimeout(function() {
  innerDiv.css('background-image', 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxR09.png)');
}, 1000)

 var outerdiv = $('.outerdiv');
  setTimeout(function() {
    outerdiv.addClass('outerdiv-opaque');
  }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pseudo, like this, which will keep your markup as is and as the `opacity` is on the pseudo it won't effect any other element.

Instead of a script, I used an extra step on the animation, where I told it to keep its `opacity` at 1 up until 60% of the animation time before it should start to fade.

```css
.outerdiv {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxR09.png);
}
.outerdiv::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation: fade 2s linear;
}
.innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
p {
  position: relative;
}
       
@keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity:1 }
  60%  { opacity:1 }
  100% { opacity:0.5 }
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
  </div>
  <p>
    content - should remain solid white
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are literally a dozen ways to do this. Here are four basic examples which work smoothly.

## Using CSS Transitions

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="outerdiv">
  </div>
  <div class="innerdiv">
  </div>
  <p>
    content - should remain solid white
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container,.outerdiv {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
}

.outerdiv,.innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.outerdiv{
  z-index:1;
  transition: .5s opacity linear;
}

.innerdiv{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxR09.png);
}

.outerdiv.fadeout{
  opacity:0
}

.container p{
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}
```

JS:

```
// wait 1 second, add the fadeout class, let the CSS do the rest
setTimeout(function(){
  document.querySelector('.outerdiv').classList.add('fadeout')
},1000);
```

**See it in action:** https://jsfiddle.net/kmm8e0x7/8/

---

## Using CSS Animation

HTML: same as above

CSS:

```
.container,.outerdiv {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
}

.outerdiv,.innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.outerdiv{
  z-index:1;
}

.innerdiv{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxR09.png);
}

.outerdiv{
  animation: fadeout .5s linear forwards 1s;      
  /* 
    Which is shorthand for:
      animation-name: fadeout 
      animation-duration: .5s;
      animation-timing-function: linear
      animation-fill-mode:forwards;
      animation-delay: 1s 
  */
}

.container p{
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}

@keyframes fadeout{
  from{opacity:1}
  to{opacity:0}
}
```

JS: none (`animation-delay` property removes the need for `setTimeout`)

**See it in action:** https://jsfiddle.net/kmm8e0x7/7/

---

## Using JavaScript

HTML: as above

CSS:

```
.container,.outerdiv {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  color: white;
}

.outerdiv,.innerdiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.outerdiv{
  z-index:1;
  transition: .5s opacity linear;
}

.innerdiv{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxR09.png);
}

.container p{
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}
```

JS:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.outerdiv');

function fadeout(){
  el.style.opacity -= 0.01;
  
  if(el.style.opacity !== 0){
      requestAnimationframe(fadeout);
      // this could just as easily be setTimeout(fadeout,t) where t = an increment of time after which to call the next frame
  }
}

// just use setTimeout to wait for 1 second before starting the fadeout
setTimeout(fadeout,1000);
```

**See it in action:** https://jsfiddle.net/kmm8e0x7/6/

---

## Using jQuery

HTML: same as above

CSS: same as above

JS:

```
$('.outerdiv').animate({
  'opacity': '0'
}, 500);
```

**See it in action:** https://jsfiddle.net/kmm8e0x7/5/

Comment: You didn't take into account the fact that I load an image behind an overlaying div that needs to remain readable.

Comment: @SB2055 I will amend shortly

Comment: @SB2055 done. Just forgot to add `position: relative; z-index: 3;` to the overlaying element, which in my example is a `p` element but could just as easily be a `div` or any other element for that matter. If you want the overlaying `p` element to be vertically and horizontally centered, you could use `position: absolute; top: 50%; left:0; right: 0; text-align: center; transform: translateY(-50%); z-index: 3;` to put the overlaying element in the center.